# OpenSSL and Java elliptic curve keys compatibility

Tags: java, openssl, bouncycastle, spongycastle

I have C application that has to generate elliptic curve private key and export it for Java application that uses Spongycastle. I need that my application produces completely the same keys as Spongycastle, so I use in OpenSSL the same format as `Spongycastle` is supposed to use for private key export, but for any reason resulted key bytes are different. Spongycastle `ECPrivateKey`.`getEncoded` method is supposed to return PKCS8 PrivateKeyInfo in DER encoding. I really can import it in OpenSSL. However, when I export it back, the key file size becames 2 times less.

Example key file is http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g90dd3019881e526c999568884712f1e3c7d48d7cc

I use following command line:

`openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform DER -in "ec.key" -nocrypt -outform DER -out "ec.p8"`

This command line is supposed to import PKCS8 elliptic curve private key and export it in the same format. However, `ec.key` file is 591 bytes, and `ec.p8` file is 295 bytes, so imported and exported key or its format is obviously different. Why?